# Where do I find the Python Crypto package when installing Paramiko on windows?

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to SFTP from Python running on windows and installed Paramiko as was recommended here. Unfortunately, it asks for Crypto.Util.randpool so I need to install the Crypto package. I found RPMS for Linux, but can't find anything or source code for windows.

The readme for Paramiko states:
pycrypto compiled for Win32 can be downloaded from the HashTar homepage:
    http://nitace.bsd.uchicago.edu:8080/hashtar.

Unfortunately, that link does not work.
Neither does the link to given from PCrypto's homepage.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) for Win32 binaries for Python 2.2 through to 2.7